# Storing char array in a class and then returning it

Tags: c++, arrays, class, char, return

I need to store a char array inside a class and then return it. I have to admit that I'm a bit confused about pointers and have tried everything I can think of but can't get it to work. Here's what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test {
public:
    void setName(char *name);
    char getName();
private:
    char m_name[30];
};

void Test::setName(char *name) {
    strcpy(m_name, name);
}

char Test::getName() {
    return *m_name;
}

void main() {

    Test foobar;
    char name[] = "Testing";
    foobar.setName(name);
    cout << foobar.getName();
}
```

Of course, I expect setName() to store the string "Testing" inside the class, and getName() should return "Testing". But instead, I get only the first letter T. What am I doing wrong?

I guess I should be using std strings but first I would like to understand why this does not work. As far as I know, this should work with char arrays as well?

Comment: Are you paying attention to the compiler warnings? :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just return a pointer:

```
const char* Test::getName() const
{
    return m_name;
}
```

and add a constructor for the `class Test` that would null-terminate the encapsulated array:

```
Test::Test()
{
    m_name[0] = 0;
}
```

so that you don't ask for trouble if someone instantiates `class Test` and doesn't call `setName()` on the instance.

Comment: I'd also suggest using strncpy() instead of strcpy(), and since this is C++, you should be using std::string instead of char pointers, which are a holdover from C

Comment: +1 regarding the use of `std::string`. If you must use a C-string for some reason, you can return a C-string by using the `c_str()` member function of `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

In `Test::getName()` you are just returning one character (first character). Instead you should return the address of the first character from where the string begins i.e. change the return type to `char*` and the return statement to `return m_name;`

Answer (score 2):

If you want this to be C++ simply dont use char pointers unless you have a very, very specific reason to do so!

Switch from char pointer to std::string and see if that solves your problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Test {
public:
    void setName(std::string name);
    std::string getName();
private:
    std::string m_name;
};

void Test::setName(std::string name) {
    m_name = name;
}

std::string Test::getName() {
    return m_name;
}

void main() { 
    Test foobar;
    foobar.setName("Testing");
    cout << foobar.getName();
}
```

For bonus points, make the parameter type in setName a const std::string&.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a pointer, `p`, the pointer dereferencing operator `*` "follows" the pointer so the expression `*p` evaluates to whatever object the pointer is pointing at.

In many situations, the name of an array such as `m_name`, can behave like a pointer. Thus, `*m_name` evaluates to the first `char` in the array, since that is the type the array name, when interpreted as a pointer, points at.

Since strings in C are represented as pointers to characters, you should not dereference the pointer, but return it intact.

Many have suggested you use `strncpy()` to write the input string into your array, since it does (sort of) bounds checking. However, it is not optimal, it's semantics are odd and copying a string into a limited buffer is really not what it was designed for. It is better to investigate if you have a variety of the `snprintf()` function in your environment, and use that like so:

```
snprintf(m_name, sizeof m_name, "%s", name);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code to get name:

```
void Test::getName()
{
std::cout << "\nYour name is: ";
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
if (Name[i] !=NULL)
std::cout << Name[i];
else break;
}
std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: +1 for the efforts. The getName function should return the name as a string and not just print it. Also using void for getName doesn't really return anything. I would suggest that in future you take a deeper look to the question asked. Kudos for your contribution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).